# HTTP request to test if requesting works fine?

Tags: unit-testing, httprequest

Is there any "gauge page" in Internet or some general procedure of querying some popular pages like Google's, so that it return constant known output?

I want to write a Unit test, which will succeeded if internet is working and data is transferring correctly.

**UPDATE**

I need namely HTTP to check all stack, including my app's part.

Comment: Do you need to use HTTP? ping would work well for testing connectivity (if at least one major website is pingable, you have internet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) (note the www). It hasn't changed since I found it, and the output is really small.

I don't think it's official or anything though.

Comment: Hmm, how do you know if this website up for 100%.

Comment: No website is up 100% of the time, but I've never seen it go down. I like it because the content doesn't change.